# concat 3 arrays into 1 array in javascript / underscore

Tags: javascript

Is there a short way / best practice to concat 3 arrays into 1 array ?

```
var arr = [],
    arr1 = [ 1 , 2 , 3 ],
    arr2 = [ 4 , 5 , 6 ],
    arr3 = [ 7 , 8 , 9 ];
arr = arr.concat(arr1);
arr = arr.concat(arr2);
arr = arr.concat(arr3);
```

Comment: arr.concat(arr1,arr2,arr3) , [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_array.asp)

Comment: you can also use `arr1+arr2+arr3` to `concat`

Comment: @MuhammadHaseebKhan: no, you can't do that in JavaScript. This will convert the three arrays to strings (calling .join(',') on each array) and concatenate the three strings. But, for example, you can use the plus operator in PHP to concatenate arrays.

Comment: you are right. i missed it

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The shortest (and fastest) solution is `arr = arr1.concat(arr2, arr3);`

Alternatives:

- `arr = arr.concat(arr1, arr2, arr3)`
- `arr = Array.prototype.concat(arr1, arr2, arr3)`
- `arr = [].concat(arr1, arr2, arr3)`

Comment: One additional alternative `arr = arr1.concat(arr2,arr3)`

Comment: @TheChrisPratt I believe that's what my answer started with.

Answer (score 13):

I would use `_.flatten`.

```
var arr = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]];
var result = _.flatten(arr) // [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Answer (score 8):

[Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) makes concatenation easy:

```
arr = [...arr1, ...arr2, ...arr3]
```

You can even include non-array items inline:

```
arr = [...arr1, 42, ...arr2, ...arr3]
```

Answer (score 4):

There's not much to be done. You can simplify it:

```
arr = arr.concat(arr1).concat(arr2).concat(arr3)
```

Or see @Radko Dinev answer for an even simpler (and better) way to do it.

If you have an array of arrays (with a variable number of arrays), you can try:

```
var m = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]];
var new_m = [];
new_m.concat.apply(new_m, m);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
_.reduce(arrays, function(result, arr) {
    return result.concat(arr)
}, [])
```

Comment: This solution only woks if OP is using underscore or lodash libraries. Javascript has a native [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method for this purpose.

Comment: I end up using lodash for doing map/reduce etc over dictionaries anyway, so I use it for doing these operations over arrays as well. But yeah, you could use Array methods if you don't want to use lodash.

Answer (score 1):

A more flexible way:

```
var arraysToConcat = [arr1, arr2, arr3];
var arr = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], arraysToConcat);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are here in 2022, there are 3 solutions (with short syntax), a b c are arrays :

```js
let x = [].concat(a, b, c);
let y = [...a, ...b, ...c];
let z = [a, b, c].flat();
```

Following benchmark : 
`z` is the worst by far.
`y` is faster with small arrays, but `x` faster with largest arrays.
 With small arrays, it's always fast.
 So, we should take the fastest answer with largest arrays : `x`