# Is it Possible to Use Underscore to Create a Javascript Objects with a Variable?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have the following situation:

```
var newObject = {user: object, user1: object1}
var user = "something";
var object = {key: [obj, obj], key1: [obj, obj]}
```

I'd want to add the following to the array of objects in var object:

```
var addToIt = [objA, objB];
```

In the end var object should look like:

```
var object = {key: [obj, obj, objA, objB], key1: [obj, obj]}
```

I believe there is a way to do it with underscore but until now I've not been able to figure it out.  A solution or suggestion would be much appreciated!

In an effort to share my approach, here is something I thought would work but I'm getting an error when I try to push and undefined values for key and key1:

```
var newHistory = _.mapObject(newObject, function(valN, keyN){
_.mapObject(valN, function(vs, ks){
if(ks = key){
return vs.push(addToIt);
}
})
})
```

Comment: Where you want to use the underscore ?

Comment: Will we have access to the keys for var object?

Comment: It’s easily possible with `object.key=object.key.concat(addToIt);` ([`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)) which makes it a near duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21811184. I’m sure the `concat` functionality has been covered on StackOverflow before, multiple times.

Comment: @Mitul, I'd like to underscore as much of it as possible as you can see above.

Comment: @turnloose, I have access to all keys.

Comment: @Xufox, it's not a matter of using concat, it's a matter of maneurvering to the right place in newObject to concat and returning newObject.

Comment: @rashadb What exactly is _“the right place in newObject”_?

Comment: @Xufox, in the example above, I addToIt is placed within key of var object and that is the right place.  I hope my solution below helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I found:

```
var newHistory = _.mapObject(newObject, function(valN, keyN){
if(keyN == key) {
return valN.concat(addToIt);
} else {
return valN;
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way and see whether this one works or not

```
_.mapObject(newObject, function(valN, keyN){

        var arr=[];
        _.mapObject(valN, function(vs, ks){

               if(ks = "key"){
                 arr.push(vs);
                 arr.push(addToIt)

               }
         });
        return arr;
    })
```